# using regex from application.yml file and use in pojo class(pattern evaluation)

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, annotations, pojo

I tried some approaches :

**1. application.yml file**

```
 internationalchar:
      regex:
        expression: "^[\\p{L}\\p{M}\\p{Nd}\\°\\' ]+$"
```

**using in POJO Class**

```
@Pattern(regexp = "${internationalchar.regex.expression}", message = "FSTU_4108,Name")
private String name;
```

error: Illegal repetition near index 0\r\n${internationalchar.regex.expression}\r\n^"

2.Also tried using escape characters

```
@Pattern(regexp = "//$//{internationalchar.regex.expression//}", message = "FSTU_4108,Name")
```

3.Using @Value attribute
@Value("${ficoInternationalChar.regex.expression}")
Not able to read my regex(giving error that not valid name)

4.

```
@Value("${internationalchar.regex.expression}")
 private String environment;
 @Pattern(regexp = environment, message = "FSTU_4108,Name")
  private String name;
```

Attribute value must be constant error(tried making envrionment as final but same error)

**NOTE : I am a java beginner**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `@Pattern` annotation does not support what you are trying to do. Its `regexp` attribute does not support placeholders and you must define the regular expression directly.

If you want to be able the externalise the pattern, you’ll have to implement a custom `ConstraintValidator`.